# iPhone 12 mini: Screen too dark in sunlight

Tags: iphone, display, auto-brightness

I switched on and off the adaptive brightnes function.
The brightness is set to maximum.

But still, I hardly can see anything on the screen, as it is too dark.
My GF's Android next to it is about double as bright.

I realized it's really hot. Didn't do much with just sitting in the sun.

Any ideas what I could try to get it brighter?
Thanks

Comment: Let it cool down. Phones (and your GF's will too) throttle performance and power consumption if they get too hot. And it also might be possible that her phone simply has a higher maximum brightness. Withouth knowing the exact model number we cant know though

Comment: You mean aside from cool it down?

Comment: Yes, cooling down had been the answer. As always heat is the problem with Apple devices. 
My GF’s Android has been sitting on the same table, lit by the same sun. P

Comment: @Andre4s yes apple devices tend to last longer, mine is still going after 5 years and my son has had 3 android in that time... I'm happy - it cost me less.

Comment: The android may simply lack the protection the iPhone has & might just run til it burns out ;) Golden rule, don't leave electronics in direct sunlight.

Comment: The Android wasn't that hot at all. The Android is black and is in a black silicon protection cover. My iPhone is blue and in a transparent silicon cover. Maybe it's because of the cover, I have to test it. But in general Apple devices are the worst with temperature management. My MBP fans are roaring constantly, even after cleaning out the dust and reaplying new thermal paste. Cooling is underdimensioned on all of them. Connecting a 4K monitor overheats the thunderbolt port chip, which has no cooling at all! Hence, the CPU is throtteling. Sorry, although it's protection, this is bad design.

Comment: @andreas Also, turning off auto-brightness will actually lower the maximum brightness. When Auto-brightness is on then it can adjust above what you can normally access.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Had been too hot. Let it cool down solved the issue.

Comment: if in a case or bumper, remove it from it, so the phone can cool down quicker.